# merge or left join R

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I have three datasets that has same Index column (Key), StudentId, and all have same number of observations, I repeat same number of observations, but different columns and different values for each observation.

```
    Dataset 1
    Id     Lab 
     1      33     
     .      .
     2334   98

    Dataset 2
    Id     Sports
     1      83     
     .      .
     2334   933

    Dataset 3
    Id     Lunch
     1      33     
     .      .
     2334   238
```

I dont know why when I use merge or left_merge to combine all the three datasets the final dataset shows up more number of rows than it should man ?

```
    Dataset Final
    Id     Sports   Lunch     Lab
     1      33       83       33 
     .      .
     3564   98       34       56
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example, i.e. data and code?

Comment: Could you also shows us your code for merge?

Comment: If the order of your `Id` is same for all 3 datasets, just use `cbind(d1,d2,d3)`.

Comment: @zx8754 thanks man thats exactly what I was looking for that solve the problem, the reason I am not able to provide a reproduceable example was because I have some comment columns that have a whole lot of text, a lot..sucker is so long it wrap to the next line and stuff like that. when I did a dput it was mess, your suggestion for cbind took care of this thing. Thanks z

Comment: @KingFrazier I put my comment as an answer, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of your `Id` is same for all 3 datasets, just use:

```
res <- cbind(d1,d2,d3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without a reproducible example, but my best guess would be that the values of your `Id` variable are slightly different in your data sets. If you're working with dplyr (what I assume given that you use `left_join`), you might instead use `inner_join()` which merges only rows that are included in *both* data sets. (However, it's likely that your final data frame will have less rows than your three data frames that you use for merging.)